# Issue with bodyToMono and READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have bellow code

```
@Data
public class Test {
   private String name;
   private Type type;

   public enum Type {
       A("a"), B("b");

       private final String value;

       Type(String value) {
           this.value = value;
       }

       @JsonValue
       public String getValue() {
           return value;
       }
   }
}

        webClient
            .get()
            .uri(url)
            .exchangeToMono(response -> response.bodyToMono(Test.class))
            .map(test -> {

            });
```

And here is the config in application.yml

```
spring:
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL: true
```

Here is the test response for the webClient call

```
{"name": "test", "type": "c"}
```

I expect `test` to be `{"name": "test"}` since `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` should ignore the unknown enum value `"type": "c"`, but actually I got `Mono.empty()`

Any idea how to make `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` work with `bodyToMono`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure WebClient codecs to use default Spring-managed Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Here is an example

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .codecs(configurer -> {
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        })
        .build();
```